# .htaccess issue in LiteSpeed Web Server

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, litespeed

Need help with litespeed web server .htaccess rules.

`http://example.com/temp/home.php` is existing URL, but now what we need to rewrite is mentioned below:

```
http://example.com/temp.php?redirect=home.php
```

And our Existing `.htaccess` code is also given below.

```
RewriteEngine on<br/>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^temp/(.*)$ temp.php?redirect=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But I don't know the issue, this rewrite still not working and shows 404 error because `temp/home.php` does not exist.

These rules are working perfectly with Apache server, but not working with Litespeed

For reference: 
https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=d15d3bca-6974-5682-902a-823c1a63e2b7

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you confirmed that mod_rewrite and `.htaccess` are enabled? Try disabling MultiViews - your script certainly won't work if MultiViews is enabled, however, neither would you expect a (server generated) 404.

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^temp/(.*)$ temp.php?redirect=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The above code will serve the content of `temp.php?redirect=home.php`.

As a test I created `temp.php` in the root directory of a domain, with the content:

```
<?php
var_dump($_GET);
```

The result when accessing `/temp/home.php` is:

```
array(1) {
  ["redirect"]=>
  string(8) "home.php"
}
```

This is tested on LiteSpeed Web Server 5.3.4 and 5.3.5.

Comment: Hey @LucasRolff what if temp.php is not in root directory?
Lets say url is: `https://example.com/dir/another_dir/temp/home.php`

Comment: @NavneetYadav, that won't work because of how the rewrite rule is done

The RewriteRule looks for `temp/` in the beginning (because of the `^`).